# Replace the value of a variable based on rest of the row in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a variable whose value takes the maximum of the other variables in that same row. I've used a for-loop and it does the job but with 220,000 observations it's rather inefficient.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  x <- c(df$var1[i], df$var2[i], df$var3[i], df$var4[i])
  df$var5[i] <- max(x)
}
```

Any ideas for a smoother work-around than iterating through each row?

Comment: Can you share a small sample of ``df`` by editing the output of ``dput(head(df))`` to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a data.table approach

```
DT[, var1234_min := do.call(pmax,.SD), .SDcols = patterns("var[1-4]")]
```

sample data

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
n = 10
DT <- data.table( id = 1:10, 
                  var1 = rnorm(n),
                  var2 = rnorm(n),
                  var3 = rnorm(n),
                  var4 = rnorm(n),
                  var5 = rnorm(n))
#    id        var1       var2       var3        var4        var5
# 1:  1 -0.56047565  1.2240818 -1.0678237  0.42646422 -0.69470698
# 2:  2 -0.23017749  0.3598138 -0.2179749 -0.29507148 -0.20791728
# 3:  3  1.55870831  0.4007715 -1.0260044  0.89512566 -1.26539635
# 4:  4  0.07050839  0.1106827 -0.7288912  0.87813349  2.16895597
# 5:  5  0.12928774 -0.5558411 -0.6250393  0.82158108  1.20796200
# 6:  6  1.71506499  1.7869131 -1.6866933  0.68864025 -1.12310858
# 7:  7  0.46091621  0.4978505  0.8377870  0.55391765 -0.40288484
# 8:  8 -1.26506123 -1.9666172  0.1533731 -0.06191171 -0.46665535
# 9:  9 -0.68685285  0.7013559 -1.1381369 -0.30596266  0.77996512
#10: 10 -0.44566197 -0.4727914  1.2538149 -0.38047100 -0.08336907
```

Comment: This did the job! Although I used e.g. `.SDcols = c("var1", "var4")` for the case where I'd want only a select few variables to be used (rather than all the variables in the row or in the range 1-4). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` row-wise:

```
df$max <- apply(df, 1, max)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you would like to get the rowmax of your dataframe.
Here is an example with iris dataset.
Using `do.call` and `pmax`

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(my_max_row = do.call(pmax, c(select(., (where(is.numeric))), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

**or** with `apply`

```
iris %>% mutate(my_max_row = apply(select(., (where(is.numeric))), 1, max))
```

output:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species my_max_row
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa        5.1
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa        4.9
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa        4.7
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa        4.6
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa        5.0
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa        5.4
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa        4.6
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa        5.0
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa        4.4
10           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa        4.9
```